# PHP simplify json array by removing empty keys

Tags: php

I need to get data from an array, but the output always varies so sometimes it has more empty keys etc.

```
    $id = "1";
    $url = file_get_contents("http://example.com/?api={$id}");
    $json = json_decode($url, true);

    foreach($json as $data)
    {
        echo $data[0][0]["test"];
    }
```

The problem is that to print values from it have to always put the number of empty keys first like `echo $data[0][0]["test"];`

How can I make it possible to only write `echo $data["test"];` under any circumstance no matter how many empty keys there are?

EDIT:
The json array

```
[
    [
        {
            "test: "testing"
        }
    ]
]
```

Comment: Please show us an example of the array structure.

Comment: Only write your function

Comment: Added the json array structure

Comment: There's no such thing as "empty keys". It's just that the JSON representation (based in some form of JavaScript array literal) allows you to omit them when *defining* the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 function printValue($array)
    foreach($array as $value){
     if(is_array($value)){
       printValue($value) 
     }
     else 
       echo $value;
  }
}
```

Basically a recursive function, if the value is an `array` dig down it else print the value.

This will work for all depths, be it on 2nd level or on 4th level.

Answer (score -1):

You could create a recursive function in order to search for a key and return it:

```
$json = '[
    [
        {
            "test" : "testing"
        }
    ]
]';
//Cast to array the json
$array = json_decode($json,true);
echo searchKey("test",$array);

function searchKey($key,$array) {
    //If key is defined, print it
    if (isset($array[$key])) {
        return $array[$key];
    }
    //Else, search deeper
    else {
        foreach ($array as $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                return searchKey($key,$value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Just use json_decode one more time before for each .
 example: $json = json_decode(json_decode($url));

Comment: This is not going to work, json_decode needs a string as input, if you you do json_decode again after a json_decode, you would be trying to decode an object or an array, and it will throw an error.